# SVG file run fine in Emulator but Gives error in Real Device?

Tags: android, svg

**I am using a SVG file in My Project to show Image. It's run fine in the emulator but gave error in the real device.**

Error is below :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23215): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
E/AndroidRuntime(23215): at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawPicture(GLES20Canvas.java:911)
E/AndroidRuntime(23215):at android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable.draw(PictureDrawable.java:73)
```

What is the reason Behind of this?

**EDIT : Solution**

```
imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

add this line to your code.

Comment: See the answer to this similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356098/using-vector-image-in-android-svg-android/18358672

Comment: One more thing is "If In the SVG file , there is 4 images like as grid   layout in  single row  and I want to choose only 2 image when I parse the SVG" what is the solution for this ? @BigBadaboom

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It might be best to start a new question so you can explain further.

Comment: @BigBadaboom: I have added a new question .. have a look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713383/a-svg-image-have-6-icon-and-need-to-choose-one

Answer (score 0):

I was not using ImageViews but placing the SVG in a Picture. I put the Picture in a custom PictureHolder class that gave the Picture x and y float values. I then used drawPicture() to put the Picture on a canvas. I couldn't get the `imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` solution to work. Using the same logic I turned off hardware acceleration for the whole app in the AndroidManifest.

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Not ideal but it worked for me with no noticeable loss of performance.