# A SVG Image have 6 icon and need to choose one?

Tags: android, svg, imageview

I have an SVG file format in which there is 5-6 icon and  I need to pick icon according to the requirement not the whole Image.

In Simply you can parse the .SVG onto your ImageView Or Canvas but this time I need to choose particular icon from the among.

**Is this possible to do with the coding or i need to draw all icon separately ?**

[image]

Somebody suggest me the way, how to make it happen ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but you may :

- Create a Bitmap with the size of your icon
- Create a new Canvas associated to this Bitmap
- Draw your svg into the Canvas with an offset
  -- If your icon coordinates are (X1, Y1)
  -- Then when you draw an element substract SVG (X1, Y1)
- Draw the Bitmap on screen.

It is a little bit homemade solution... maybe there is some libraries doing those king of things for you.

Comment: According to different different resolution , is it right way to do this ?

Comment: Your svg is expressed in px, isn't it? This is the same issue than when you draw it on screen, no ?

Comment: Maybe a good solution for the resolution issue is to convert your svg to a drawable with https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/

Comment: I have already done this thing ... This time i need to pick a particular area /pixel/icon.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a clip and translation on the canvas before drawing to hide all but the icon you want, but I think the best course of action is to use separate image files.

Comment: ok ... let me see what will happen. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which SVG library you are using.  If you are using AndroidSVG, you could add `<view>` elements to your SVG (one for each icon) and select the appropriate icon to draw using renderViewToPicture() etc.