# android:load svg file from web and show it on image view

Tags: android, svg, imageview, picasso, svg-android

I want to load a svg file from the web and show this file in an ImageView. For non vector images I use the [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library.

Is it possible to use this library for svg files as well?
Is there any way to load svg files from the web and show it in an ImageView?
I use the [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) library to show svg files but i don't know how to get svg images from the web all the examples for this library use local files.

Comment: " is ther any way to load svg file from web and show it on image view ?" -- use `HttpUrlConnection`, HttpClient, OkHttp, Volley, Ion, or any number of other HTTP client libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please refer to [Having issue on Real Device using vector image in android. SVG-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356098/having-issue-on-real-device-using-vector-image-in-android-svg-android)

In the users post he asks a similar question and suggest he uses:

Create a member variable for the ImageView in your layout file;

```
private ImageView mImageView;

// intialize in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
```

Download the image

```
private class HttpImageRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable> {
    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {


            final URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            SVG svg = SVGParser. getSVGFromInputStream(inputStream);
            Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
            return drawable;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
        // Update the view
        updateImageView(drawable);
    }
}
```

Then Apply the drawable to the Imageview

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void updateImageView(Drawable drawable){
    if(drawable != null){

        // Try using your library and adding this layer type before switching your SVG parsing
        mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

SVGParser is available at https://github.com/pents90/svg-android

Comment: it`s returm me this error : com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParseException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: No input specified. for this line :  SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(inputStream);

Comment: Yes. this method expects XML returned, and i was using a .svg file. So i am going to update my answer with a valid XML source. Sorry for the delay

Comment: @mahdi Please see updated answer which can actually refer to .svg or .xml files. this is because .svg really contains xml

Comment: getting error org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: no element found in this line SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(inputStream);

Comment: how to load .svg or .xml file using Picasso android...onBitmapfailed() called everytime

Comment: @AshishPatel see https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/ it is in OP's questions since it is the library he is using

Answer (score 46):

Update: For newer version please checkout the Glide Samples
(https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg)

-

You can use Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0) and AndroidSVG (https://bitbucket.org/paullebeau/androidsvg).

There is also a sample from Glide: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/svgsample/app

Setup  GenericRequestBuilder

```
requestBuilder = Glide.with(mActivity)
    .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, mActivity), InputStream.class)
            .from(Uri.class)
            .as(SVG.class)
            .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
            .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
            .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
            .decoder(new SvgDecoder())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_facebook)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_web)
            .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
            .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());
```

Use RequestBuilder with uri

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#/media/File:SVG_logo.svg");
            requestBuilder
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                            // SVG cannot be serialized so it's not worth to cache it
                    .load(uri)
                    .into(mImageView);
```

Comment: You sir, saved my day :D

Comment: what is requestBuilder?
what is SvgDrawableTranscoder?
what is SvgDecoder?
what is SvgDecoder?
what is SvgSoftwareLayerSetter?

Comment: Please look at the sample from Glide:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/svgsample/app

Requestbuilder is a "GenericRequestBuilder" from Glide (http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/index.html)

SVGDrawableTranscoder, SVGDecoder and SVGSoftwareLayerSetter are Classes to extend Glide to load and display SVGs with the help of AndroidSVG.

Comment: good example from glide 3.6.0, but I didn't know how to do it on 4.0.0. btw if you could downgrade to 3.6.0 ( like I did on my project )  its works perfectly!

Comment: where to get SvgDrawableTranscode(), SvgDecoder().. please if you can post the link.

Comment: Both class can be found in the "sample from Glide" in the answer.
 https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/v3.6.0/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/svgsample/app

Comment: Many thanks! But I had to downgrade my Glide version. Please update your solution to the latest version of Glide (4.3.1).

Comment: @Rags93 The code is not saving image for offline for me. Anything else needed to manage offline saving

Comment: Maybe this on from the Glide Issues can help you: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1239

Comment: I'm using glide 4.9.0, there are a lot of changes. to you have any up to date example?

Answer (score 11):

Use this `Glide based library` loading xml

Add dependency

```
  compile 'com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.0'
```

for latest android dependency Gradle use this instead

```
implementation 'com.github.ar-android:AndroidSvgLoader:1.0.0'
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_item);            

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivimage);

        SvgLoader.pluck()
                .with(this)
                .setPlaceHolder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .load("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/Z/2/b/a/6/android-toy-h.svg", image);

    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SvgLoader.pluck().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glide has a pretty annoying license (one of the more confusing ones I've seen in a while) Would be nice to have a solution that does not require I present license docs in my app.

Comment: Also include this inside project build.gradle file:
allprojects {
  repositories {
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
 }

Comment: this library gives me this error : Program type already present: com.caverock.androidsvg.CSSParser$Attrib

Answer (score 7):

**Kotlin and Coil Library to load SVG from URL:**

1. Add Kotlin image loading library to build.gradle (Module: app) (It also supports other images):

Gradle:

```
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil:1.4.0'
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.4.0'
```

or

Kts:

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.4.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.4.0")
```

2. Add below extension function to any Kotlin file of your project,
   (outside of a class not inside of a class):

Here I used AppCompatImageView in xml, if you use only ImageView replace AppCompatImageView by ImageView from below function.

```
fun AppCompatImageView.loadSvgOrOther(myUrl: String?, cache: Boolean = true, errorImg: Int = R.drawable.logo_round // Place any error image from your drawable) {

myUrl?.let {
    if (it.lowercase().endsWith("svg")) {
        val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
            .componentRegistry {
                add(SvgDecoder(this@loadSvgOrOther.context))
            }.build()

        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context).apply {
            error(errorImg)
            placeholder(errorImg)
            data(it).decoder(SvgDecoder(this@loadSvgOrOther.context))
        }.target(this).build()

        imageLoader.enqueue(request)
    } else {
        val imageLoader = ImageLoader(context)

        val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context).apply {
            if (cache) {
                memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            } else {
                memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
            }
            error(errorImg)
            placeholder(errorImg)
            data("$it")
        }.target(this).build()

        imageLoader.enqueue(request)
    }
  }
} // loadSvgOrOther
```

3. Now use like below:

   ```
   myAppCompatImageView.loadSvgOrOther("https[:]//example[.]com/image.svg")
   ```

Hope this will help, who wants to use Kotlin to load svg, png, jpg etc Images.

Comment: in my case SvgDecoder class not find. Can you help me the process of calling it

Comment: @AminulHaqueAome Also add this line in gradle: 
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:0.11.0")
(Answer updated)

Comment: yeah I also tried that. But the problem was, it was conflicting between the version of coil and coile svg. May be I can solve the issue today. And Thanks for your reply vai

Comment: vai, another question. How can I use placeHolder in this method?

Comment: For placeholder or other options you can see the official documentation here: https://github.com/coil-kt/coil

Comment: @Touhid imageLoader.execute(request) got error and say function must be suspend. why?? . and why LoadRequest is unknown??

Comment: @Sadegh Try to use mentioned version (0.11.0) of coil. if you use the latest version then please go throw their official documentation. https://github.com/coil-kt/coil

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507893/does-glide-have-a-method-for-loading-both-png-and-svg/67242151#67242151

Answer (score 4):

Hope the below code is useful for you.

1. Add this dependency in **build.gradle**

   `implementation 'com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0'`
2. Now start working in **MainActivity.java**

   `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivimage);`

   `String url= https://your_url/banking.svg`
     `GlideToVectorYou.init().with(this).load(Uri.parse(url),image);`

Comment: this is great, thanks! just note - that also in project level gradle file, need to add:  `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`  , under `repositories`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library

https://github.com/2coffees1team/GlideToVectorYou

As he say : "The library is based on Glide and offers the same functionalities + svg support".

Answer (score 0):

> **Load SVG using Glide V4 or above**

> Add dependencies in app.gradle > dependencies

```
implementation 'com.github.qoqa:glide-svg:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

> Make new class SampleAppGlideModule.java and go to Build>Make Project(ctrl+f9)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder;
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class SampleAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {



    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return super.isManifestParsingEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder);
        builder.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG);
    }
}
```

> Load SVG using Glide V4 or above

```
GlideApp.with(this)                      
.load(contentLangModels.get(i).getContentImage()).into(contentLangBinding.ivExtra);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coil Image loading library,

Add the following dependencies to your app level build.gradle file,

```
def coilVersion = '1.2.2'
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:$coilVersion"
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-svg:$coilVersion"
```

Now create this method,

```
fun ImageView.loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl: String) {
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
    .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@loadImageFromUrl.context)) 
}
    .build()

val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context)
    .crossfade(true)
    .crossfade(300)
    .data(imageUrl)
    .target(
        onStart = {
            //set up an image loader or whatever you need
        },
        onSuccess = { result ->
            val bitmap = (result as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
            this.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            //dismiss the loader if any
        },
        onError = {
            /**
             * TODO: set an error drawable
             */
        }
    )
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(imageRequest)
```

}

Now you can call this extension function from your ImageView,

```
imgView.loadImage(imageUrl)
```

This will work for svgs, pngs. I have not tried it with jpgs, but should work with them as well.