# Does Glide have a method for loading both PNG and SVG?

Tags: java, android, svg, android-glide

I'm using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load some images **asynchronously** into some of my `ImageView`s, and I know it can handle images like `PNG` or `JPG` as it can handle `SVG`.

Thing is, As far as I know, the way I load those two kinds of image differs. Like:

**Loading "normal" images**

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("URL")
                .into(cardHolder.iv_card);
```

**Loading SVG**

```
GenericRequestBuilder<Uri, InputStream, SVG, PictureDrawable> requestBuilder = Glide.with(mContext)
        .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, mContext), InputStream.class)
        .from(Uri.class)
        .as(SVG.class)
        .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
        .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
        .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<>(new SVGDecoder()))
        .decoder(new SVGDecoder())
        .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());

requestBuilder
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .load(Uri.parse("URL"))
        .into(cardHolder.iv_card);
```

And if I try to load SVG with the first method it won't work. If I try to load PNG or JPG with the second method, it won't work either.

**Is there a generic way to load both image types using Glide?**

The server where I'm fetching those images from don't tell me the image type before I download it. It's a REST server and the resource will be retrieved in a way like `"http://foo.bar/resource"`. The only way to know the image type is reading the HEAD response.

Comment: you might want to clarify what do you mean by *or the other way around it won't work*.

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/) & [AndroidSVG](http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) together to achieve your goal.

There is sample from Glide for SVG.[Sample Example](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src)

> Setup RequestBuilder

```
requestBuilder = Glide.with(mActivity)
    .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, mActivity), InputStream.class)
    .from(Uri.class)
    .as(SVG.class)
    .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
    .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
    .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
    .decoder(new SvgDecoder())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_facebook)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_web)
    .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
    .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());
```

> Use RequestBuilder with uri

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg");
requestBuilder
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
    // SVG cannot be serialized so it's not worth to cache it
    .load(uri)
    .into(mImageView);
```

This way you can achieve your goal. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm loading SVG's. But I don't know beforehand if the image is a SVG or a PNG. So the loading can fail.

Comment: From URL you can find the image is SVG or PNG then redirect it to particular requestBuilder

Comment: Okay, how? And it has to happen asynchronously.

Comment: You are downloading the image from server using the URL right, You know the URL

Comment: I'm not downloading it *before*. I'm using Glide's `load` method.

Comment: load("https://www.google.es/images/srpr/logo11w.png") and load("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Svg_example3.svg") with URL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103968/discussion-between-mauker-and-maheshwar-ligade).

Comment: Any resolution on this? I'm in the same position. My url does not contain .svg or .png or any indication of what type of image it is, I could download the file beforehand and check the headers but it's not a very good solution.

Comment: @Dane I don't have optimized solution but I have workaround

Comment: You have way to find the solution like that using try cache, by default assume the png format and load the URL, if exception occur then handle the same URI using the svg loader, Is it not the best option but defiantly work

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I have done that, with the view recycling it causes some problems, the images load most of the time, but sometimes it just doesn't show. Thanks for your reply, I'll continue that way.

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade Is any gradle required for that. transcode is not resolving in my code

Comment: @Aditi the dependency is only i added in gradle is glide one

Comment: This may be an issue with glide lib version

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I am here using 4.2.0 version

Comment: Unable to  load .PNG Image

Comment: Anyone know how to do this in Xamarin Android?

Comment: @Justin I am not sure about the Xamrin Glide API but you can try the same logic

Comment: How to do it in version 4.9.0

Comment: There is no `.using()`

Comment: The link to example you provided has couple issues: caching svg and resizing. This two issues addressed here https://github.com/bumptech/glide/pull/5172

Answer (score 16):

**ALTERNATIVE WAY : kotlin + Coil**

**This solution will work well with .svg , .png , .jpg**

add dependency:

```
//Coil (https://github.com/coil-kt/coil)
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.5.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.5.0")
```

add this function to your code:

```
fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String) {
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .components { add(SvgDecoder.Factory()) }
        .build()

    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .crossfade(true)
        .crossfade(500)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .data(url)
        .target(this)
        .build()

    imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

Then call this method in your activity or fragment:

```
  imageView.loadUrl(url)
  // Sample SVG url : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Red_jungle_fowl_white_background.png
```

Comment: If I replace the URL with a PNG will that also work?

Comment: @Mauker Yes, that will work well. I tested that with .png and .jpg urls. you can test it if you want and tell me the feedback.

Comment: does this take SVG as string also?

Comment: @Sattar Yes. fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String)

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi did you add both of dependencies : implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.2.0")

Answer (score 9):

I added a flexible decoding pipeline to decode an image or SVG, maybe can help! based on [glide SVG example](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg)

> Decoder

```
class SvgOrImageDecoder : ResourceDecoder<InputStream, SvgOrImageDecodedResource> {

override fun handles(source: InputStream, options: Options): Boolean {
    return true
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun decode(
    source: InputStream, width: Int, height: Int,
    options: Options
): Resource<SvgOrImageDecodedResource>? {
    val array = source.readBytes()
    val svgInputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(array.clone())
    val pngInputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(array.clone())

    return try {
        val svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(svgInputStream)

        try {
            source.close()
            pngInputStream.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {}

        SimpleResource(SvgOrImageDecodedResource(svg))
    } catch (ex: SVGParseException) {
        try {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(pngInputStream)
            SimpleResource(SvgOrImageDecodedResource(bitmap = bitmap))
        } catch (exception: Exception){
            try {
                source.close()
                pngInputStream.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {}
            throw IOException("Cannot load SVG or Image from stream", ex)
        }
    }
}
```

> Transcoder

```
class SvgOrImageDrawableTranscoder : ResourceTranscoder<SvgOrImageDecodedResource, PictureDrawable> {
override fun transcode(
    toTranscode: Resource<SvgOrImageDecodedResource>,
    options: Options
): Resource<PictureDrawable>? {
    val data = toTranscode.get()

    if (data.svg != null) {
        val picture = data.svg.renderToPicture()
        val drawable = PictureDrawable(picture)
        return SimpleResource(drawable)
    } else if (data.bitmap != null)
        return SimpleResource(PictureDrawable(renderToPicture(data.bitmap)))
    else return null
}

private fun renderToPicture(bitmap: Bitmap): Picture{
    val picture = Picture()
    val canvas = picture.beginRecording(bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, RectF(0f, 0f, bitmap.width.toFloat(), bitmap.height.toFloat()), null)
    picture.endRecording();

    return picture
}
```

> Decoded Resource

```
data class SvgOrImageDecodedResource(
val svg:SVG? = null,
val bitmap: Bitmap? = null)
```

> Glide Module

```
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
override fun registerComponents(
    context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry
) {
    registry.register(SvgOrImageDecodedResource::class.java, PictureDrawable::class.java, SvgOrImageDrawableTranscoder())
        .append(InputStream::class.java, SvgOrImageDecodedResource::class.java, SvgOrImageDecoder())
}

// Disable manifest parsing to avoid adding similar modules twice.
override fun isManifestParsingEnabled(): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

}

Comment: Glide v4 loads a little slower than library for SVG loading using Glide v3, but library for SVG caused troubles using gradle (Glide different versions). If u don't care much about SVG speed, Josue's answer is nice and fast way to implement loading both SVG and PNG pictures

Comment: After further testing there is one problem with this - some SVGs are blurry. But merging this solution with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680109/image-becomes-blurry-when-loading-svg-with-glide I managed to load both pngs and svgs and make them not blurry

Answer (score 2):

GlideToVectorYou did not work for me, so I used [coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) with coil-svg extension library

Comment: I have never thought I would upvote an answer that only mentions library but You saved my time :D

Comment: although we ended up with glide with svg decoder, I am glad I helped :D

Answer (score 1):

For others who reach this thread because they're looking for a way to load SVG's in Xamarin Android, the accepted answer won't work because a lot of those classes / methods don't seem to be available in the Xamarin Glide nuget package. Here is what worked for me:

```
public static void SetSvgFromBytes (this ImageView imageView, byte[] bytes, int width, int height) {
            // Load the SVG from the bytes.
            var stream = new MemoryStream (bytes);
            var svg = SVG.GetFromInputStream (stream);
            // Create a Bitmap to render our SVG to.
            var bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (width, height, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
            // Create a Canvas to use for rendering.
            var canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
            canvas.DrawRGB (255, 255, 255);
            // Now render the SVG to the Canvas.
            svg.RenderToCanvas (canvas);
            // Finally, populate the imageview from the Bitmap.
            imageView.SetImageBitmap (bitmap);
        }
```

It requires the [AndroidSVG.Xamarin](https://github.com/jamesmundy/Xamarin.AndroidSVG) nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still needs it, with Glide v4 you can use [Glide-SVG](https://github.com/qoqa/glide-svg) library for adding SVG support easily to Glide.
You only need to import [Android SVG](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) library too, and you can render any SVG with Glide using this simple, standard line of code:

```
GlideApp.with(this).load(url).into(imageView)
```

where GlideApp is your locally generated Glide Module, like the following:

```
@GlideModule
class GlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun isManifestParsingEnabled() = false

    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder)
        builder.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I import both glide-svg and android-svg I get an compilation error saying `Duplicate class com.caverock.androidsvg found in modules jetified-androidsvg-1.4` with nearly 100 duplicate classes.

Comment: Try using these lines to add the libraries:

implementation "com.github.qoqa:glide-svg:2.0.4"
api "com.caverock:androidsvg:1.4"

I wrote them in two different projects with a lot of other libraries and I never had troubles.

Answer (score 0):

For Glide 4+ use this library called [GlideToVectorYou](https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou) which uses Glide internally.

```
fun ImageView.loadSvg(url: String?) {
    GlideToVectorYou
        .init()
        .with(this.context)
        .setPlaceHolder(R.drawable.loading, R.drawable.actual)
        .load(Uri.parse(url), this)
}
```

Source: [How to load remote svg files with Picasso library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915396/how-to-load-remote-svg-files-with-picasso-library)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem what i have done solved my problem you just have 2 do 2 things which work perfectly
Go to the link https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou
1- just copy past maven dependancy to project build
allprojects {
repositories {
...
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
2-add the dependency in app build
like            implementation 'com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0'

thanks it will resolve to load the svg make sure that you are loading same as i am doing

Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
.load(imageurl)
.apply(new RequestOptions()
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
.dontAnimate()
.fitCenter())
.into(holder.image);

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sharp library, in place of the Glide library

```
implementation 'com.pixplicity.sharp:library:1.1.0'

InputStream stream = response.body().byteStream();
                   Sharp.loadInputStream(stream).into(target);
                    stream.close();
```

An example can be seen here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-load-svg-from-url-in-android-imageview/

```
fun fetchSvg(context: Context, url: String, target: ImageView) {
    val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cache(Cache(context.cacheDir, 5 * 1024 * 1014))
        .build()
 
    val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            // we are adding a default image if we gets any error.
            target.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_app_logo)
        }

        @Throws(IOException::class)
        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response) {
       
            response.body()?.apply {
                val stream = this.byteStream()
                Sharp.loadInputStream(stream).into(target)
                stream.close()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

use code

```
 if(item.logo.endsWith("svg"))
               Media.fetchSvg(icon.context,item.logo, icon)
            else{
               Glide.with(icon.context).load(Uri.parse(item.logo)).into(icon)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, Coil has an issue. you can't load SVG and PNG- JPG,etc .at the same time so this solution will be as workaround using the Extension function

1- Make sure you use this dependency

- For normal images `implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:2.5.0"`
- For SVG images `implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.5.0"`

2- Create an exception file name it Extension.Kt

3- Create this extension function

```
import android.widget.ImageView
import coil.ImageLoader
import coil.decode.SvgDecoder
import coil.request.ImageRequest
import com.codestation.football_league_application.R

fun ImageView.loadImageUrl(imageUrl: String) {
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .components { add(SvgDecoder.Factory()) }
        .build()

    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .crossfade(true)
        .crossfade(1000)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .data(url)
        .target(this)
        .build()

    imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

4-In your adapter or Activity/Fragment call your `imageView.loadImageUrl`
extension function and pass image Url to It as a parameter.

```
  imageView.loadImageUrl(imageUrl)
```