# class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I am trying to load an image into `imageView` through Glide. But the image is not loaded - I get an error. 
I'm using the following code

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load(itemData.getThumbnailUri())
    .placeholder(R.mipmap.koya_logo_white)
    .error(R.mipmap.ic_image_loading_error)
    .into(itemBinding.cover);
```

Logs

```
lide: Load failed for https://s3.amazonaws.com/koya-dev-videos/kindness/8da807aa-1e1e-413d-bf9b-5bb084646593/medialibrary/9456621508/videos/1eb78337-d569-41bd-95ad-153d9098de03.png with size [1080x1080]
```

```
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{StringUri->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL, DataCacheKey{sourceKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/koya-dev-videos/kindness/8da807aa-1e1e-413d-bf9b-5bb084646593/medialibrary/9456621508/videos/1eb78337-d569-41bd-95ad-153d9098de03.png, signature=EmptySignature}
Cause (1 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{StringUri->Drawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 2): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{StringUri->Bitmap->Drawable}
```

Comment: whats glide version you are using ?

Comment: I'm using Glide version 4.8.0

Comment: Try printing the value of `itemData.getThumbnailUri() ` in logs and check if its valid URI format or not

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif Please read [When should code formatting be used for non-code text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/6296561)

Comment: Could you find a solution to your issue? I have the same problem for two/three days.

Comment: Hey! What solution?? I have the same issue on android 22 api and below - cant load url like screen of camera 4mp, ex: https://fs05.naveksoft.com:62121/a109b1b0-4f05-45f2-9e55-35d672d13038/preview.mp4?token=e7638665ffdd79a0924b71bb0da12ed95e39981a-iVsYbGnEyq6scGe-1568397893-1568311493

Comment: Even I too. facing the same problem,At first Loading of images I'm facing this problem from the 2nd loading the images are loading from cache so they are loading normally.

Comment: did some one found solution for this problem ?

Comment: Using 4.11 Glide also facing same issue based on phone manufacturer and model...any solution?

Answer (score 6):

**Try this solution...**

```
String url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/koya-dev-videos/kindness/8da807aa-1e1e-413d-bf9b-5bb084646593/medialibrary/9456621508/videos/1eb78337-d569-41bd-95ad-153d9098de03.png";
    
GlideApp.with(context).load(url)
        .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
        .error(R.drawable.glide_app_img_loader)
        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
             @Override
             public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 return false;
             }
    
             @Override
             public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 return false;
             }
        }).into(imageView);
```

Comment: class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 2 causes:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Forbidden)
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Forbidden)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE

Comment: are you sure you are using only HTTPS urls ?

Comment: @VishrutMavani thanks for the great tip!  I had no idea you could do this.

Comment: I'm not using url, but internal storage and the override with target sizes did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The solution works for me:
    1. Update build.gradle(Module: app)

```
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1"
        kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1"
        implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0"
        implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.7.1'){
            exclude group: 'glide-parent'
        }
```

2. Set timeout for glide

   ```
    @GlideModule
       class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {
           override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
               val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                   .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .build()
               val factory = OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client)
               glide.registry.replace(GlideUrl::class.java, InputStream::class.java, factory)
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Another reason why this problem appears is the phone/emulator doesn't have an internet connection.

Comment: If it still didn't worked, try uninstall and re-install the app. Hope it works!

Answer (score 6):

**Simplest solution**

add,

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

inside your `<application/>` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: @IlyaGazman exactly, The default value target API level 27 or lower is "true". Apps that target API level 28 or higher default to "false"

Comment: it worked for me! you don't need this when using api level 8 downwards but when working on api 8.1 and above you will need this particular solution

Answer (score 2):

Update the Glide version to :

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Am also faced this issue.Its bug from glide side.Use the latest version of glide.

```
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 google()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

Make sure that itemData.getThumbnailUri() not contain empty space

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.
When I wrote the layout like this

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/view_height">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and I changed that to

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/view_height">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same with @ievgen answers.

- Check for your internet connection
- HTTPS connection issue for **Android 8** or **9**, see [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3336#issuecomment-425625743)
- The issue might occur due to invalid [URL](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3616#issuecomment-485472467) or having a trailing space or `/` slash

My project was getting an API from TMDB, and using `val BASE_IMAGE = http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/` notice the last trailing `w780/` "slash"?

It is concatenated mistakenly e.g:

`W/Glide: Load failed for http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780//qJdfO3ahgAMf2rcmhoqngjBBZW1.jpg with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]`

Removing the trailing `/` slash fixed my issue. E.g from:

```
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780/ -> http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780
```

Here's my setup:

```
Glide: 4.9.0
Android Studio: 3.4.1 (Grale Build Tools)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create image decoder like this:

```
class PageDecoder(
    private val bitmapPool: BitmapPool
) : ResourceDecoder<InputStream, Bitmap> {

    companion object {
        val PAGE_DECODER: Option<Boolean> = Option.memory("abc")
    }

    override fun decode(source: InputStream, width: Int, height: Int, options: Options): Resource<Bitmap>? {
        return BitmapResource.obtain(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(source), bitmapPool)
    }

    override fun handles(source: InputStream, options: Options): Boolean = options.get(PAGE_DECODER) ?: false

}
```

In your glide module should apply this:

```
override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.prepend(InputStream::class.java, Bitmap::class.java, PageDecoder(glide.bitmapPool))
    }
```

In activity there you load image use this:

```
GlideApp.with(context)
        .load("Image url or path, etc")
        .apply(GlideOptions.option(PageDecoder.PAGE_DECODER, true))
        .into(imageview)
```

It's work for me, I hope it's was helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0):

for me the url was `" https//app.domain.."`
the issue here is the space at the beginning of the url

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
Glide.with(this)
   .load(imageItem.img_url.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build())
   .into(mars_image)
```

Try to extend your url with `load(imageItem.img_url.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build())` this extension for https.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is what worked for me. Replacing the http to https.

```
   if (url.startsWith("https")) {
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .error(R.drawable.thumblin)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imageView);
    } else {
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(url.replace("http","https"))
                .error(R.drawable.thumblin)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if the Uri you are passing is correct ,for me it was bug in the Uri being passed as I was Appending the required BaseUri twice

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in Kotlin

```
 Glide.with(context).load(url)

                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL,Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL).listener(
                                object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                                        e: GlideException?,
                                        model: Any?,
                                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                                    ): Boolean {
                                        return false
                                    }

                                    override fun onResourceReady(
                                        resource: Drawable?,
                                        model: Any?,
                                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                                    ): Boolean {
                                        return false
                                    }

                                }
                            ).into(imageView)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

I was having same problem with Glide + AndroidSVG as some Vector images were not loaded and having to check between SVG and PNG for Glide to process correctly.

here is the [alternate solution presented by @sadegh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67242151/4776675) . Please go ahead to direct answer.

**ALTERNATIVE WAY : kotlin + Coil**

**This solution will work well with .svg , .png , .jpg**

add dependency:

```
//Coil (https://github.com/coil-kt/coil)
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.4.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.4.0")
```

add this function to your code:

```
fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String) {

val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
    .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@loadUrl.context)) }
    .build()

val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context)
    .crossfade(true)
    .crossfade(500)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .data(url)
    .target(this)
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

Then call this method in your activity or fragment:

```
  imageView.loadUrl(url)
  // url example : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Red_jungle_fowl_white_background.png
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to uninstall your app from emulator and try compile again. It's working for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

As we use the AWS and with my experience to it found that **`Glide`** is not able to load `HTTP` URLs but works fine if we use `HTTPS` over the `HTTP`.

Also, it fails to loads large images for say resolution 1800x1800 or more.

Why? It fails to load that much data of an image on some specific device due to less heap. So the best option is to use `RequestOptions` and apply it to the `Glide`.

```
try {
    String url = "" /* URL of Image */;

    if (url.startsWith("http://"))
        url = url.replace("http://", "https://");

    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.mipmap.app_icon);
    requestOptions.error(R.mipmap.app_icon);
    Glide
        .with(context)
        .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
        .load(url)
        .into(imgView);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -7):

I think you did not add permission for your app to access the Internet.

> Add this into your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```