# Glide is not loading "joeschmoe" avatars into ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I am trying to load a joeschmoe avatar into my ImagView by using glide library.
I am doing this:-

```
   Glide.with(getActivity())
                .asBitmap()
                .load("https://joeschmoe.io/api/v1/random")
                .into(imageView);
```

but the avatar is not loading ;

I also tried:-

```
     Glide.with(getActivity()).load("https://joeschmoe.io/api/v1/random").into(imageView);
```

but is doesn't work also.

Logcat readings are:-

```
    class java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: 
    status = 0x80000000
    2020-03-26 01:12:45.833 21573-21573/com.example.hdwallpapers I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 2)
    java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSourceCallback failed: status = 0x80000000
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder.decode(VideoDecoder.java:185)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:92)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:70)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:59)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:76)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:57)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:524)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:488)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:474)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:426)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:390)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataFetcherReady(SourceGenerator.java:176)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DataCacheGenerator.onDataReady(DataCacheGenerator.java:94)
```

Comment: try this method it will fix your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508121/5673068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this joeschmoe.io website and did an inspect element in my browser. the image is not a bitmap, it is `SVG` image. to load svg with glide i suggest to look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508121/8136868).

Answer (score 0):

Glide doesn't support SVG, as per checking the link it's trying to give you an SVG file, try a JPG or PNG