# How to convert image/svg+xml from API with retrofit 2

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, retrofit2, simple-xml-converter

Using Retrofit converter-gson and converter-simplexml to get response from API in "Content-Type: image/svg+xml"

Retrofit:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(myURL)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

Api:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: image/svg+xml")
@GET("/get-qr-code/{uuid}")
suspend fun getQR(
    @Path("uuid") uuid: String
): String
```

Error:

```
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
    com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Or if I put addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create()) on top of gson converter, I get this error:

```
Could not deserialize body as class java.lang.String
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not deserialize body as class java.lang.String
```

And Response from API is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <svg width="98mm" height="98mm" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="8mm" y="8mm" width="2mm" ………. width="2mm" height="2mm"/></svg>

44514-byte body
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a famous image loading library called [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/). It is capable of loading images with the help of an URL. You can also use AndroidSVG Library for it.
See this Answer for more details: [Does Glide have a method for loading both PNG and SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35507893/does-glide-have-a-method-for-loading-both-png-and-svg)