# Android: covert SVG to VectorDrawable

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have SVG icons coming from endpoint, and I need to convert them to VectorDrawable somehow at runtime. Surprisingly after some research I didn't find any working solutions. Is there any way yo do it?

I know in Android Studio there is a simple way to add SVG files as resources  by using build-in converter. Which basically converts SVG to VectorDrawable. But I need to do conversion in runtime.

Comment: I'm not aware of a runtime SVG to VectorDrawable converter.  But there *are* SVG rendering libraries for Android that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glide and AndroidSVG together to load svg images.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508121/5313283