# Is it possible to load SVG on Fresco Lib?

Tags: java, android, svg, fresco

I'm using a modified version of [this slider lib](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) that uses [fresco lib](http://frescolib.org/) instead of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

I'm getting the `SVG` from a RESTful server as a String. And the loading process works somewhat like:

```
protected void bindEventAndShow(final View v, SimpleDraweeView targetImageView){

    // ...

    // This URL is provided elsewhere, just putting it here for readability.
    String url = "http://foo.bar/resource";

    ControllerListener controllerListener = new BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo>() {
        // onFinalImageSet(), onIntermediateImageSet(), onFailure methods here
    }

    DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder().setControllerListener(controllerListener)
                        .setImageRequest(ImageRequest.fromUri(url))
                        .build();

    // ...

    targetImageView.setHierarchy(hierarchy);
    targetImageView.setController(controller);
}
```

When I provide a URL with `PNG` or `JPEG`, it works wonders. But if the URL gives back a `SVG`, it doesn't work at all.

I want to know if it's possible to load a `SVG` String/File directly into Fresco. If it's not possible directly, how can it be done?

**P.S.:** I could try to transform it to `PNG` or `JPG`, save it on disk and only then load it on the slider, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Comment: Did you try with Glide? I thnik this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30938082/2971619.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acording with github repository, they dont support svg.

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1008

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/329

You should use other library like glide.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

An example:

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg

Comment: Marking as accepted, as Fresco doesn't really support SVG. Using Glide seems to be the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

You still can make it work use Fresco library with custom SVG decoder.

Have a look [this example here](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/imageformat/svg).