# How to load svg image by an external link?

Tags: android, image, svg, android-glide

I am trying to load svg image through an external link(https://restcountries.eu/data/ind.svg) into an imageview in android application using glide but it throws error. So i'm open to suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: check this, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215625/androidload-svg-file-from-web-and-show-it-on-image-view

Comment: No, its not. actually i was trying to use **RequestBuilder** provided by **Glide** but it is not recognizing **using**  method. Please help if you have any idea to resolve this error. Thanks.