# java.lang.IllegalStateException:New Glide Version Failed To Load SVG Image

Tags: android, svg, imageview, android-glide

I have using glide 4.6.1 to load image into the image view but it fails. Previously I was using Glide 3.6.0 to load the image in the imageview. The glide version 3.6.0 works fine and load the image perfectly from URL. To make it work from Glide 3.6.0, I followed this article [android:load svg file from web and show it on image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215625/androidload-svg-file-from-web-and-show-it-on-image-view). However, glide 4.6.1 is not loading **SVG** image in the image view and giving exception.

My code is :

```
requestBuilder = GlideApp.with(context)
                .as(PictureDrawable.class)
                .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter());
requestBuilder.load(uri).into(imageview);
```

THe officical Glide Github also shows this example I am also following that article https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg.

The exception I am getting is:

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.lang.IllegalStateException(Failed to find any load path from class android.net.Uri$StringUri to class android.graphics.drawable.PictureDrawable)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

Is there any way to make Glide 4.6.1 work in a similar way to Glide 3.6.0 fro loading SVG?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah got the solution was missing @GlideModule from SvgModule Class. So it should be:

```
**@GlideModule** //was missing this
public class SvgModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide,
                                   @NonNull Registry registry) {
        registry.register(SVG.class, PictureDrawable.class, new SvgDrawableTranscoder())
                .append(InputStream.class, SVG.class, new SvgDecoder());
    }

    // Disable manifest parsing to avoid adding similar modules twice.
    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is the right answer, but if you use kotlin - do not forget to add this  - apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' to your app module build.gradle and also check the http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html#kotlin, you need to add also 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'