# How to load remote svg files with Picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

I'm building an android app that requires downloading svg images from a server.
I have tried using Picasso the usual way but it displays nothing.

```
Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView)
```

Is there anyway to display vector images with Picasso?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30938082/9381524) is answer about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a library called [GlideToVectorYou](https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou) which uses Glide internally.

```
fun ImageView.loadSvg(url: String?) {
    GlideToVectorYou
        .init()
        .with(this.context)
        .setPlaceHolder(R.drawable.loading, R.drawable.actual)
        .load(Uri.parse(url), this)
}
```

or You can also use Coil library to load svg. Just add these lines in build.gradle

```
// ... Coil (https://github.com/coil-kt/coil)
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:0.12.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:0.12.0")
```

Then Add an extension function

```
fun AppCompatImageView.loadSvg(url: String) {
    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
        .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@loadSvg.context)) }
        .build()

    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context)
        .crossfade(true)
        .crossfade(500)
        .data(url)
        .target(this)
        .build()

    imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

Then call this method in your activity or fragment

```
your_image_view.loadSvg("your_file_name.svg")
```

Comment: As per question, it's about Picasso lib not any possible way, so I'd consider your answer as out of topic. Sometimes there is no way to change the main image loading lib just for a single use case and we definitely should not add another lib for it!

Answer (score 0):

use coil in kotlin for handle svg files

first add

```
// Coil
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.2"
implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.3.2"
```

then use

```
fun ImageView.loadImage(imageUri: String, placeholder: Int? = null) {

val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
    .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@loadImage.context)) }
    .build()

load(uri = imageUri, imageLoader = imageLoader) {
           crossfade(true)
           placeholder(placeholder ?: R.drawable.image_avatar)
       }
   }
```

Comment: and this is compose code?, why you attach dependency of coil compose?

Answer (score -1):

My advice, try to move to Glide library. Under hood, lib could load svg and much more things.
[Here is an examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215625/androidload-svg-file-from-web-and-show-it-on-image-view).