# Error while loading image with Glide, Picasso , Coli , Fresco

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide, fresco

I can't load images from the API https://github.com/Teknologica/meta-weather-test-app because I use this URL https://www.metaweather.com/static/img/weather/s.svg never load the image in glide and Picasso the listener return me below error.

Error `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000`

I read the docs and the error is because 0x80000000 means that the file is incomplete, corrupted, or something like that. but if you go to the URL look at complete the image.

My code with the coil is very simple

```
imageView.load("https://www.metaweather.com/static/img/weather/s.svg")
```

and with Picasso its

```
 Picasso.with(context)
                .load(String.format(ConstantesRetrofit.API_FILES_URL, estadoClimaSufijo))
                .error(R.drawable.ic_cloud)
                .into(holder.iVTipoClima);
```

that's it I feel very please with the person who helps me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915396/how-to-load-remote-svg-files-with-picasso-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check out this sample: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg/MainActivity.java