# How to load svg URL with glide and set in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-glide

Below is my code;

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
     .load("https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/AJ_Digital_Camera.svg")
     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
     .into(img_resturant);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215625/androidload-svg-file-from-web-and-show-it-on-image-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy with Glide to do from scratch, I would recommend using [this library](https://github.com/ar-android/AndroidSvgLoader)

I have used this in one of my project, **under the hood it used Glide** and gets the job done.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView image;
private String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    url = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/Z/2/b/a/6/android-toy-h.svg";

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    SvgLoader.pluck()
            .with(this)
            .setPlaceHolder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .load(url, image);
}

@Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SvgLoader.pluck().close();
}
}
```

Comment: in this image is not showing

Comment: Without activity this library not working.